# Optimize PHP CURL for web crawler

Tags: php, linux, curl, curl-multi

I am trying to code a crawler based on PHP with curl. I have database of 20,000-30,000 URLs that I have to crawl. Each call to curl to fetch a webpage takes around 4-5 seconds.

How can I optimize this and reduce the time required to fetch a page?

Comment: related SO question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139704/multi-thread-multi-curl-crawler-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `curl_multi_*` for that. The amount of curl resources you append to one multi handle is the amount of parallel requests it will do. I usually start with 20-30 threads, depending on the size of returned content (make sure your script won't terminate on memory limit).

Note, that it will run as long as it takes to run the *slowest* request. So if a request times out, you might wait for very long. To avoid that, it can be a good idea to set timeout to some acceptable value.

You can see the code example at my answer in another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738836/uploading-multiple-files-using-php-via-curl?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

Comment: in your code, which loop does all the downloading? The while loop with curl_multi_exec or the for loop with curl_multi_getcontent?

Comment: Do you mean *when do I get the content of the pages I request?* If that, then `$content = curl_multi_getcontent` is what you want. `$content` here is analog of `$content = curl_exec($ch);`.

Comment: I mean when the download is actually happening. I can process all the pages later sequentially. I don't need the processing to be multi threaded. Just the downloading part is sufficient. If curl_multi_getcontent is equivalent to curl_exec, I can't see where the parallel downloading is happening since I am just downloading pages in a loop, which I feel can be done with single threaded curl also. What am I missing here?

Comment: The download itself is happening in a middle loop where the line `curl_multi_exec($cmh, $running);` is. With `curl_multi_getcontent` you just get the content of the downloaded page. About `curl_exec` I meant that it returns the content. I didn't mean it executes at that point.