# Uploading multiple files using PHP via curl

Tags: php, curl, upload, ftp

I am trying to transfer two files via PHP using cURL. I know the methodology via the command line would be

```bsh
curl -T "{file1,file2,..filex}" ftp://ftp.example.com/ -u username:password
```

And within php you can upload 1 file via the following code

```
$ch = curl_init();
$localfile = "somefile";
$username = "Someusername@someserver.com";
$password = "somerandomhash";
$fp = fopen($localfile, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://ftp.domain.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
curl_exec ($ch);
$error_no = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

But how would I do multiple files using the above methodology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the same credentials to connect to FTP in parallel, you could try to do that with minimum changes via `curl_multi_*` with the code like this:

```
$chs = array();
$cmh = curl_multi_init();
for ($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++)
{
    $chs[$i] = curl_init();
    // set curl properties
    curl_multi_add_handle($cmh, $chs[$i]);
}

$running=null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($cmh, $running);
} while ($running > 0);

for ($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++)
{
    $content = curl_multi_getcontent($chs[$t]);
    // parse reply
    curl_multi_remove_handle($cmh, $chs[$t]);
    curl_close($chs[$t]);
}
curl_multi_close($cmh);
```

Comment: That would be great but unfortunately I need to upload the two files in sequence using the same connection. So File1, then File2, however files 3 and 4 can be uploaded using a different connection, which in fact is what I'm trying to achieve. So to summarize file 1 then file2, while concurrently file3 then file 4, ad infinium.

Comment: You can still use the code I provided, simply running it twice without the lines: `curl_multi_remove_handle($cmh, $chs[$t]);`, `curl_close($chs[$t]);` and `curl_multi_close($cmh);`

Comment: Isn't this more targeted towards downloading files as opposed to uploading files? I need to be able to upload multiple files.

Comment: It's just a tool, it's up to you how you use it. You might need to do less threads while uploading, but that's simply due to the fact that more resources are required for it.

Comment: hi @Ranty i am trying above code but not work for multiple files it upload only single file to remote server